# Oh no! Hats are coming

Tags: discussion, hats, winter-bash

The year is rapidly coming to a close, which means even though we typically [hate it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268583/164200), it’s time to have some fun...with hats!  That’s right - it’s time for Winter Bash 2016!!

Most of you remember previous years’ events, but here is a quick little reminder. Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users have fun by earning “hats” for their avatars by completing certain tasks (very similar to badges). We track everyone’s progress using hats in a leaderboard that looks similar to this:

[image]

As always, The FTE's of StackExchange have come up with **new hat designs** for this year’s fun!

## The Details

The event will run from **19 December 2016** up to and including **08 January 2017**. Users will be able to see all the hats they’ve earned on http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

Comment: You forgot the most important thing. There is an unicorn on the countdown page.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Not viewable on iPad though. I had to switch to PC to see it :-)

Comment: Went to check just to see the unicorn.

Comment: @BennySkogberg yep, I know. Most of the page gets cut off on smaller resolutions. But you have to give them some merit too - playing a little with the browser responsive design test tools, seems that the page is centered on the counter, so the countdown should be still visible on most devices.